# asp.net dropdownlist too big, viewstate probably full, postback

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, viewstate

I got a page with multiple dropdownlist. Each of them are fill with a lot of stock.I need the selected value of each of them on postback.

My problem is, at the end of the post back it take so much time to refresh(show) the page.
and I saw that the viewstate is fill with a lot of thing.

I try to disable viewstate for my dropdownlist, but that erase my value on postback.

I already have a conpressor for viewstate.

can you help me.

Comment: How many items are in this DropdownList exactly?

Comment: some can have thousands.

Comment: your question made me think. I will replace my dropdownlist who's containing too much things, to an auto-complete textbox. Ajax will take data, and the postback will be less filled.

Comment: That sounds like a more user-friendly UI than 1000's of items in a dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Page Caching - based on `OutputCache property of page`

Link Sample : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Link Configuration : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178606%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Page Caching or disable viewstate and add selected values to session and get that values at pageload again.

Comment: I will look at that. but I cant disable viewstate, I have somes things that I keep inside(I need those on each page. not a lot of thing, but still)